# Why is φύσις often used for "body" in today’s English?

Tags: etymology, greek

The Greek root *φύσις* means *natural* or *of nature*, but in present-day English it is often used as if it meant *bodily* or *of the body*:

- a physical examination
- physiotherapy
- physique

Why is the root used this way? Why not use the Greek word for *body* in these instances?

In an informal poll of three educated adults, I asked them what they thought the roots of *tele*, *physi*, and *micro* mean. All properly guessed *tele* and *micro*, and all improperly guessed *physi* meant body or some form thereof.

Comment: I don't understand *physical* to mean *bodily*, but as opposed to *virtual*: that is, real, concrete, having a tangible existence. Putting that aside: questions of *why* are, generally speaking, inapplicable to language development. Languages just *are*:  accretions of centuries and millennia of unaccountable and inaccessible accidents of history. Asking *why* we use *physi-* this way is about as sensible as asking *why* some branch on a tree is precisely 17.612' long, extending at an angle of precisely 78.622* from he trunk. Why? *Cause that's how it grew*.

Comment: There's a pretty good treatment here http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=phys&searchmode=none that makes a good starting point for further research. --->

Comment: @chasly from UK: That's interesting. So it seems that ultimately, ***physic*** descends [from  PIE root ***bheue-** = "to **be**, exist, grow". Spelling with ph- attested from late 14c.](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=physic&allowed_in_frame=0)

Comment: These words were created from and grew on from 'physician' and 'physics' (not exactly used in the same contexts). Words slowly change meaning or are coined to nearby meanings. You're drawing a conclusion based on a folksonomy (informal guessing) rather than the real provenance.

Comment: The verb φύω, of which φύσις is a nominalization, means *grow,* primarily in the vegetative sense, and this strongly shapes the ancient meaning of φύσις. See Gerard Naddaf, *The Greek Concept of Nature* (Albany: State U of New York P, 2005).

Comment: @DanBron 'Why' questions are answerable, just not easily in a Q&A format. 'why' is a more general question that needs lots of _different_ examples to see a pattern, which then points to an underlying cause) so that an unknown example can be guessed. That needs discussion at length which just doesn't fit well here. Why did the trunk grow that way? Weight of the wood, hormones, sunlight, etc. lots of biological theory too much to give here. For this particular trunk? There's no 'why' just description of how it grew at particular intervals.

Comment: @Mitch Someone once said to me "*if there are lots and lots of rules, then there are no **rules***". A *why* should have a fundamental, overarching, governing reason. If the only answer to *why* is a long and elaborate story with lots of incidental and accidental details shaping the final result, that's not a reason, not an answer, it's a story.

Comment: What @Dan said. The only real issue with such "explanations" is *How much does quantum indeterminacy come into play?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh those darn wishy-washy quanta! No better than politicians, really.

Comment: @Dan: Would those be the politicians we voted into office when we exercised free will in an election? I suspect they're actually the ones alluded to in *It doesn't matter who you vote for - the @!**?# *government always wins*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The noun **phisik** and related words already refer to the knowledge of medicines and their effects on the organs of the human body when they enter Middle English via Latin and Old French, earliest English attestations in the late 14th century. English speakers today would naturally associate *physi* with things relating to the body and bodily health.

http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=142073546&egdisplay=open&egs=142097098

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have a date for when this morpheme was first attested to have had the sense of body/medicine/health in *any* language? (Ideally, Greek itself.)

Comment: When *phys* first came to refer primarily or exclusively to health and disease in Greek or Latin, I really don't know. One might start by looking in early Byzantine medical texts.

Comment: Thank you! User [chasly from UK](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/127726/chasly-from-uk) posted a link to [the etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=phys&searchmode=none) which supports your answer.